# Show X and Y share the same cumulative distribution function and same density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $c > 0$ and $X \sim $ Unif$[0, c]$. Show that the random
variable $Y = c − X$ has the same cumulative distribution function as $X$ and hence also the same density function.

I have proved that $X$ and $Y$ share the same cumulative distribution function by $P(Y≤x)=P(c-X≤x)=P(X≥c-x)=1-P(X<c-x)=1-F(c-x)=F(x)$, where $F(x)$ is the cumulative function.

Comment: Well, you have already shown what you need. Since both these distributions are absolutely continuous, differentiating both these CDFs yields equal densities (but having proved that they share a common CDF is enough to show that they have the same distribution).

Comment: $1-P(X<c-x)=1-F(c-x)$ is true here since $P(X=c-x)=0$.  Also $1-F(c-x)=F(x)$ here since they are both $\frac{x}{c}$ when $0 \le x \le c$.  In both cases it would be better if you justified your statements.